# More efficient way to change scatter plot colors in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, performance, pyqtgraph

**Background**: I am creating a GUI that will show the updating current values in 4 arrays of hexagonal pixels. I think the easiest way to do this is to create a scatter plot of the layout in  pyqtgraph and update the face/brush color according to the sensor data.

**Method**: I have basically cribbed the pyqtgraph example scripts ScatterPlotItem.py and ScatterPlotSpeedTest.py and adapted them to my specific layout.

**Problem**: The performance is very slow, much slower than I would expect given that the example pyqtgraph scripts run at 1000+ fps. My script currently runs at ~4-7 fps. This is quite surprising since I assumed only changing the color of a point would be quite fast. I'm still learning pyqtgraph and use `ScatterPlotItem.setBrush()` in the function `update`, but it appears to be quite slow (I think this is the source of the slow update). Is there a better/faster way to update the face color of a scatter plot item?

Here is the script that I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore
from time import perf_counter


# This function generates the hexgonal array x's and y's in the required ordering.
# It is ugly, but works for now.
def drawHexGridLoop2(origin, depth, apothem, padding):
    
    def getCoords(xs, ys):
        xs = [item for sublist in xs for item in sublist]
        ys = [item for sublist in ys for item in sublist]
        coords = list(zip(xs, ys))      
        return coords
    
    def flattenList(l):
        rv = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
        return rv
    
    ang60 = np.deg2rad(60)
    xs = [[origin[0]]]
    ys = [[origin[1]]]
    labels = [['1']]
    labelN = 2
    thisX = 0
    thisY = 0
    for d in range(1, depth):
        thisXArr = []
        thisYArr = []
        thisLabelArr = []
        loc = 1
        n=0
        while n < d*6:
            if n == 0:
                anchorN = 0
                thisX = round(xs[-1][0] + 2*apothem, 8)
                thisY = round(ys[-1][0], 8)
                anchorX = xs[-1][anchorN]
                anchorY = ys[-1][anchorN]
                thisXArr.append(thisX)
                thisYArr.append(thisY)
                thisLabelArr.append(str(labelN))
                labelN += 1

            else:
                thisX = round(anchorX + 2*apothem*np.cos(-1*ang60*loc), 8)
                thisY = round(anchorY + 2*apothem*np.sin(-1*ang60*loc), 8)
                if (thisX, thisY) in getCoords(xs, ys):
                    anchorN += 1
                    anchorX = xs[-1][anchorN]
                    anchorY = ys[-1][anchorN]
                    loc -= 1
                    continue
                thisXArr.append(thisX)
                thisYArr.append(thisY)
                thisLabelArr.append(str(labelN))
                labelN += 1
                loc += 1
            n += 1              
        xs.append(thisXArr)
        ys.append(thisYArr)
        labels.append(thisLabelArr)
    xs = flattenList(xs)
    ys = flattenList(ys)
    labels = flattenList(labels)
    return xs, ys, labels


# Function to create the scatter plot in each viewbox.
# Adapted from ScatterPlotItem.py
def createArray(w):
    s = pg.ScatterPlotItem(
        pxMode=False,  # Set pxMode=False to allow spots to transform with the view
        hoverable=True,
        hoverPen=pg.mkPen('g'),
        hoverSize=hexSize
    )
    spots = []
    xs, ys, labels = drawHexGridLoop2((0, 0), 14, 1e-6, 0)
    for i, thing in enumerate(xs):
        spots.append({'pos': (xs[i], ys[i]), 'size': hexSize, 'pen': {'color': 'w', 'width': 2}, 'brush':pg.intColor(10, 10), 'symbol':'h'})
    s.addPoints(spots)
    w.addItem(s)

    return w, s, spots, xs, ys

hexSize = 2.2e-6
app = pg.mkQApp("Scatter Plot Item Example") 
mw = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
mw.resize(800,800)
view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()  ## GraphicsView with GraphicsLayout inserted by default
mw.setCentralWidget(view)
mw.show()
mw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ScatterPlot')
view.ci.setBorder((50, 50, 100))

## create four areas to add plots
w1 = view.addViewBox()
w1.setAspectLocked()
w2 = view.addViewBox()
w2.setAspectLocked()
view.nextRow()
w3 = view.addViewBox()
w3.setAspectLocked()
w4 = view.addViewBox()
w4.setAspectLocked()

# Create the scatter plots.
w1, s1, spots1, xs, ys = createArray(w1)
w2, s2, spots1, xs, ys = createArray(w2)
w3, s3, spots1, xs, ys = createArray(w3)
w4, s4, spots1, xs, ys = createArray(w4)

# Create the color map.
# Adapted from https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/1712#issuecomment-819745370
nPts = 255
colormap = pg.colormap.get('cividis')
valueRange = np.linspace(0, 255, num=nPts)
colors = colormap.getLookupTable(0, 1, nPts=nPts)

# This is really slow!
fps = None
lastTime = perf_counter()
def update():
    global fps, lastTime
    z = np.random.randint(0,255, size=547)
    brushes = colors[np.searchsorted(valueRange, z)]
    s1.setBrush(brushes) # Is there a faster way to do this?
    s2.setBrush(brushes)
    s3.setBrush(brushes)
    s4.setBrush(brushes)
    now = perf_counter()
    dt = now - lastTime
    lastTime = now
    if fps is None:
        fps = 1.0 / dt
    else:
        s = np.clip(dt * 3., 0, 1)
        fps = fps * (1 - s) + (1.0 / dt) * s
    mw.setWindowTitle('%0.2f fps' % fps)

    
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem of your solution, is that you're passing an array of colors into setBrush method. In that case PyqtGraph has to generate new brushes for every frame. This is your bottleneck.

To speed things up, you can create brushes_table, which will contain brushes instead of colors. Then in update function you just generate array of indexes and from them, new array of brushes. Now PyqtGraph will use those brushes instead of creating new one for every frame.
**Performance went up from ~7fps to 35fps.**

Here is your modified example:

```
import time

import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from time import perf_counter


# This function generates the hexgonal array x's and y's in the required ordering.
# It is ugly, but works for now.
def drawHexGridLoop2(origin, depth, apothem, padding):
    def getCoords(xs, ys):
        xs = [item for sublist in xs for item in sublist]
        ys = [item for sublist in ys for item in sublist]
        coords = list(zip(xs, ys))
        return coords

    def flattenList(l):
        rv = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
        return rv

    ang60 = np.deg2rad(60)
    xs = [[origin[0]]]
    ys = [[origin[1]]]
    labels = [['1']]
    labelN = 2
    thisX = 0
    thisY = 0
    for d in range(1, depth):
        thisXArr = []
        thisYArr = []
        thisLabelArr = []
        loc = 1
        n = 0
        while n < d * 6:
            if n == 0:
                anchorN = 0
                thisX = round(xs[-1][0] + 2 * apothem, 8)
                thisY = round(ys[-1][0], 8)
                anchorX = xs[-1][anchorN]
                anchorY = ys[-1][anchorN]
                thisXArr.append(thisX)
                thisYArr.append(thisY)
                thisLabelArr.append(str(labelN))
                labelN += 1

            else:
                thisX = round(anchorX + 2 * apothem * np.cos(-1 * ang60 * loc), 8)
                thisY = round(anchorY + 2 * apothem * np.sin(-1 * ang60 * loc), 8)
                if (thisX, thisY) in getCoords(xs, ys):
                    anchorN += 1
                    anchorX = xs[-1][anchorN]
                    anchorY = ys[-1][anchorN]
                    loc -= 1
                    continue
                thisXArr.append(thisX)
                thisYArr.append(thisY)
                thisLabelArr.append(str(labelN))
                labelN += 1
                loc += 1
            n += 1
        xs.append(thisXArr)
        ys.append(thisYArr)
        labels.append(thisLabelArr)
    xs = flattenList(xs)
    ys = flattenList(ys)
    labels = flattenList(labels)
    return xs, ys, labels


# Function to create the scatter plot in each viewbox.
# Adapted from ScatterPlotItem.py
def createArray(w):
    s = pg.ScatterPlotItem(
        pxMode=False,  # Set pxMode=False to allow spots to transform with the view
        hoverable=True,
        hoverPen=pg.mkPen('g'),
        hoverSize=hexSize
    )
    spots = []
    xs, ys, labels = drawHexGridLoop2((0, 0), 14, 1e-6, 0)
    for i, thing in enumerate(xs):
        spots.append(
            {'pos': (xs[i], ys[i]), 'size': hexSize, 'pen': {'color': 'w', 'width': 2}, 'brush': pg.intColor(10, 10),
             'symbol': 'h'})
    s.addPoints(spots)
    w.addItem(s)

    return w, s, spots, xs, ys


hexSize = 2.2e-6
app = pg.mkQApp("Scatter Plot Item Example")
mw = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
mw.resize(800, 800)
view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()  ## GraphicsView with GraphicsLayout inserted by default
mw.setCentralWidget(view)
mw.show()
mw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ScatterPlot')
view.ci.setBorder((50, 50, 100))

## create four areas to add plots
w1 = view.addViewBox()
w1.setAspectLocked()
w2 = view.addViewBox()
w2.setAspectLocked()
view.nextRow()
w3 = view.addViewBox()
w3.setAspectLocked()
w4 = view.addViewBox()
w4.setAspectLocked()

# Create the scatter plots.
w1, s1, spots1, xs, ys = createArray(w1)
w2, s2, spots1, xs, ys = createArray(w2)
w3, s3, spots1, xs, ys = createArray(w3)
w4, s4, spots1, xs, ys = createArray(w4)

# Create the color map.
# Adapted from https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/1712#issuecomment-819745370
nPts = 255
colormap = pg.colormap.get('cividis')
valueRange = np.linspace(0, 255, num=nPts)
colors = colormap.getLookupTable(0, 1, nPts=nPts)

# *** Create brushes lookup table
brushes_table = [QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(*color)) for color in colors]

fps = None
lastTime = perf_counter()


def update():
    global fps, lastTime
    z = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=547)
    # *** Create array of already created brushes from lookup table
    brushes = [brushes_table[i] for i in z]
    s1.setBrush(brushes)  # Now update is much faster!
    s2.setBrush(brushes)
    s3.setBrush(brushes)
    s4.setBrush(brushes)
    now = perf_counter()
    dt = now - lastTime
    lastTime = now
    if fps is None:
        fps = 1.0 / dt
    else:
        s = np.clip(dt * 3., 0, 1)
        fps = fps * (1 - s) + (1.0 / dt) * s
    mw.setWindowTitle('%0.2f fps' % fps)


timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```